# SSLException on Eclipse for Linux

Tags: eclipse, sslexception

I am getting this error when I try to authentic my org on eclipse. I am running eclipse 4.3 on ubuntu 15.04. Anyone having the same issue or any way to go about fixing this?

Thanks.

[image: SSLExeption Error]